# PHP DOMXPath query to return value

Tags: php

I want to get and show the title, tel, fax and address if they exist.

HTML code could be like :

```html
<div id="id1"> 

   <div class="AB">

     <ul>

       <li class="title"> AGENCE X </li>

        <li class="tel"> 060000000</li>

       <li class="fax"> 06000000</li>
       
       <li class="address> this is the address </li>

      </ul> 

   </div>

   <div class="AB">   //the same class name
    <ul>
        <li class="titre"> AGENCE X </li>

        <li class="tel"> 060000000</li>

         <li class="fax"> 06000000</li>

    </ul>
    </div>

    <div>...</div>

   </div>
```

I wrote this code but I didn't know how to write the condition "if a node with class name 'address' or 'fax' or 'tel' exist' then do *X*.

Here is my code:

```js
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://website.com');

$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div') ;
$xpath=new DOMXPath($doc);
$titre=$xpath->query('//div/ul/li[@class="titre"]');
$adresse=$xpath->query('//div/ul/li[@class="adresse"]');
$phone=$xpath->query('//div/ul/li[@class="phone"]');
$fax=$xpath->query('//div/ul/li[@class="fax"]');

$a=0;$b=0;$c=0;

for($i=0;$i<$titre->length;$i++)
{
 echo $titre->item($i)->nodeValue.'<br/>' ;

   if(a "li" has classe="adresse" existe)
    { for($a=0;$a<$adresse->length;$a++) 
           {
       echo $adresse->item($a)->nodeValue.'<br/>' ;
       $a++;
       }
     }
  if(a "li" has classe="titre" existe){  for($b=0;$b<$phone->length;$b++) 
      {
     echo $titre->item($b)->nodeValue.'<br/>' ;
     $b++;
    }
  }
 if(a "li" has classe="fax" existe) { for($c=0;$c<$fax->length;$c++) 
        {
    echo $fax->item($c)->nodeValue.'<br/>' ;
    $c++;
      } 
  } 
   
}
```

Could someone tell me how can I would write this condition or another solution?

Comment: When you say _get_ and show what do you mean? When you do your echo statements you could wrap them in an `if` block. For instance `if ($fax->length > 0) { // Show this node }`.

Comment: what i want is to show for every title(company) his telephone number , fax and adress if they exist . so i can put them in a database .